# Backing up Jenkins on Windows fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to backup my Jenkins home directory.

I try to make a copy of my Jenkins home directory, but Windows complains that it cant find most of the directories (it seems to be all the folder links within the jobs folder).

I also try and zip or rar the directory using WinRAR, but it also complain about those same folder which are "missing".

I am assuming these will then be corrupt backups.

Using the ThinBackup plugin for Jenkins basically makes a copy as well as far as I can see, however, the "linked folders" seem to now be real folders within the backup.  I am not sure if this means I will be able to restore.

Surely backing up Jenkins on a windows environment is the norm and been done thousands of times before?

How do you guys go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(WS.10).aspx) has a /b flag to copy symlinks as simlinks

> /b Copies the symbolic link instead of the files. This parameter was introduced in Windows Vista®.

So something like

```
echo d | xcopy /b /e Jenkins_DIR Jenkins_backup_DIR
```

Will allow you to make a copy of the jenkins structure as it is in your live instance.

In practice this is not really necessary. Jenkins recreates those linked folders if they don't exist (or if they are replaced with real folders).  You can give it a go by deleting a linked folder or two in a job (back them up first if you want).  Individual build number links aren't recreated, but the other links -  lastSuccessful etc are regenerated as soon as you visit the page for a project.

The upshot is that your thinBackup will work fine.  If you really want a compressed archive, then [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) with it's .7z format supports archiving symlinks, although like the thinbackup plugin it will create copies of the linked folders.